# Can I use my Windows 8 Key to upgrade an unlicenced Windows 7 Version?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I'm having a problem regarding my Windows version

I installed Windows 7 on my new Desktop but unfortunately it wouldn't accept my Key that I got from my university. So I install/edit without having it licensed. Now i got a Windows 8 Key from my university as well.

Is it possible to upgrade my unlicensed Version of Windows 7 that i got on my desktop to a licensed Windows 8 Version? I would really like to not need to formate my complete system as I had problems with the Windows 8 installation on a empty hard drive earlier. =(

Comment: I doubt it... otherwise everyone would 'acquire' versions of W7 and only pay for upgrades to W8 instead of full price

Comment: It sounds like your windows 7 key is an upgrade key. If you put in a windows 7 disk inside your windows 7 trial PC, you can upgrade from windows 7 to windows 7 and your key will be accepted. But to answer your question about windows 8, I am not sure. It works with windows 7 so I see no reason why it wouldn't work with windows 8.

Comment: You might want to ask yourself two things: 1) Do I want to run windows 8? If so do I want a neat clean installation with no extra leftovers from an upgrade? 2) If I am happy with windows 7, then why did the windows 7 key not work? For which version was the key (ultimate, prof, ...) DId I use the matching DVD (or a DVD with the ei.cfg removed) ?

Comment: Both keys i have are full verion keys i got provided by my university. I actually use my windows 7 key for the OS on my laptop as well, it should be possible to use the key for more than one computer (at least for other people in my course it is possible). 
My Windows 7 Key is for Professional - as is the installed OS on my desktop. The key should fit for the dvd i used to install as i burned it myself with the ISO i got provided by dreamspark.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use Microsoft's upgrade assistant, available for download here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8

This should scan your computer and walk you through the steps of upgrading, otherwise you will have to reformat your drive to install it properly.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read this seems like it is possible to do.

*Windows 8* doesn't seem to check the validity of either the "Windows Genuine" or activation status of the *Windows 7* install before upgrading to *Windows 8*.

Have a look at this article where the author talks about upgrading both pirated and un-activated copies of Windows 7.

http://techpp.com/2012/10/26/upgrade-to-windows-8-from-illegal-windows-7/

I might add, that while this is technically possible, I'm not sure how *ethical* it is, but I think that's a decision you have to make.